# Не работает виджет

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

Изучаю виджеты, делаю все по гайду из оф.сайта, но возможно я кое что упускаю...

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sakuraso13.fun.widget">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".widget.WidgetService" android:label="widget"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android_black"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/xml_widget" />
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**XML виджета**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:minHeight="45dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_android_black"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

**Layout виджета**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:text="Текст 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Текст 2"
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Текст 3"
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Class виджета**

```
public class WidgetService extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt1,"123");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt2,"123");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt3,"123");
        for(int x=0;x<appWidgetIds.length;x++){
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[x],remoteViews);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Log.d("123","onEnabled");
    }

}
```

Когда добавляю его на экран текст не меняется на 123, и в логах "onEnabled" и "onUpdate" я тоже не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые устройства требуют обязательное наличие еще этих атрибутов в XML файле

```
android:minResizeWidth="120dp" 
android:minResizeHeight="45dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что onEnabled вызывается только единожды (!). [Ниже цитата из документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets):

> Это называется, когда экземпляр приложения виджет создается для первого время. Например, **если пользователь добавляет два** экземпляра виджета вашего приложения, **это называется только в первый раз.** Если вам нужно открыть новую базу данных или выполнить другие настройки, которые только нужно происходят один раз для всех экземпляров виджетов приложений, то это хорошее место, чтобы сделать это.

А точность вызова метода onUpdate не гарантируется системой. На моем опыте встречалось такое, что после первоначального виджета на рабочий экран он не обновлялся ещё минут 5-10. Рекомендуется предварительно инициализировать содержимое виджета.

В манифесте для виджета пропишите:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
</intent-filter>
```

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".widget.WidgetService" android:label="widget"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android_black"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/xml_widget" />
    </receiver>
```